# Objective-C: Is it possible to see full error-path?

Tags: objective-c, error-handling

How to know full stack of error?

I want to know, if it's possible, to see a full stack of functions, that were called.

I have an hierarchy of functions, that have hierarchy "general"->"very specialized".

Suppose, that i have 5-level hierarchy.

Each function have completion error-block, that defined like this:

```
typedef (^ErrorBlock)(NSError*error)

FunctionWithManyParams:(Param1Type*)param1.... onError:(ErrorBlock)ErrorBlock;
```

And each function in hierarchy have the same part of code:

```
onError(NSError*error){
    ErrorBlock(error);
}
```

So, if i called function from **high level (suppose n)**, it will call function from **(n-1) level** and etc.

And if function from **1-level** have a error, it will callbacked to very-high-level function (very specialized), that call it.

Is it possible to know full path of this call? (or some technique for it)?

I want to have full trace of function-calls, so, i need to added something like this:

```
    onError(NSError*error){
       NSString*errorDescription = [self getNameOfFunction];
       NSMutableDictionary * errorDictionary = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
       NSString*previousErrorDescription = [error description];

       [errorDictionary setValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ >> %@",previousErrorDescription,errorDescription ] forKey:NSLocalizedDescriptionKey];
            NSError * errorNew = [NSError errorWithDomain:vkDomain
                                                  code:errorCode
                                              userInfo:errorDictionary
                               ];
        ErrorBlock(errorNew);
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps you need:

```
NSLog(@"%@",[NSThread callStackSymbols]);
```

Comment: That's cool! I didn't know there was a simple Objective-C call, until now I was toying with the `backtrace()` C calls when I wanted to see the call stack...

Comment: can i know the full name of function in it body somehow? like `[self nameOfCurrentFunction]`

Comment: @loldop, maybe you should try `NSStringFromSelector(_cmd)` if you want the method name for the context.